# Does casting to base class involve boxing and unboxing

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class, boxing, unboxing

Having below classes:

```
public abstract class FieldElementBaseCL : FormElementBaseCL
{
    public FieldElementBaseCL(FormElementGroupBaseCL parentElement, int linkedFieldID) : base(parentElement)
    {
        LinkedFieldID = linkedFieldID;
    }

    [DataMember]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int LinkedFieldID { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public LabelControl LabelComponent { get; set; }

    public abstract FieldElementDTOBase GetElementDTO();

}

[DataContract]
public class FieldElementNumberEditCL : FieldElementBaseCL
{
    public FieldElementNumberEditCL(FormElementGroupBaseCL parentElement, int linkedFieldID) : base(parentElement, linkedFieldID)
    {

    }

    public override FieldElementDTOBase GetElementDTO()
    {
        FieldElementNumberEditDTOCL elementDTO = new FieldElementNumberEditDTOCL();

        return elementDTO;
    }
}
```

As you see, there is line which creates instance of `FieldElementNumberEditCL` class. So, does `GetElementDTO` involve boxing/unboxing as its return type is `FieldElementBaseCL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boxing and unboxing is only applicable to value types.  Value types are those declared with `struct`.  You are not using `struct`, you are using `class`.  Therefore, boxing/unboxing is completely inapplicable to you.